# How can i add purchase order in XERO using an API?

Tags: php, api

I need to add purchase order in XERO using an API. But, i can't get the endpoint for this service.
Please Let me know if you have any idea about this.

Thanks ahead the time.

Comment: Perhaps reciepts? http://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/receipts/#POST

Answer (score 1):

This is a reply from official XERO

> not at the moment, I’m afraid. We’ll be assessing demand for an import
>   function and the API team could come to the rescue with support there
>   – again this will depend on demand.

source :https://www.xero.com/blog/2013/11/purchase-orders/

Answer (score 1):

You can now create purchase orders through the Xero API using the /purchaseorders endpoint.

Documentation is here: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/purchase-orders